# How to use the twitter4j lib to get the tweets of screen name?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, tweets

I have seen a lot of tutorials for using this lib but i dint get a clear idea of it.

Firstly how can i authenticate the twitter app??,

is there any way i can hardcode the access token, so that the user does'nt have to do anything he can directly search for the particular user's tweet by entering the screen name??

How can i get the tweets after mentioning a screen name??

I tried reading the docs with twitter4j lib but it dint help me....

I need help im stuck in this from two days , Plz help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to authenticate:

- [The standard 3-legged authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/3-legged-authorization) : I'll be explaining this briefly in this answer.
- [Pin-based authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization) : For applications which cannot access or embed a web browser.
- [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth) : Functions as an Application Authorization, so the user does not need to log in but uses the application to authorize.

First of all you will need to create an application [here](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new).
You will then receive your consumer key and secret:

[image: Consumer key]

You can then use this code to request authorization at start up.

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // TwitterProperties
    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer httpOauthConsumer;
    private OAuthProvider httpOauthprovider;

    public final static String consumerKey = "YOUR CONSUMER KEY";
    public final static String consumerSecret = "YOUR CONSUMER SECRET";

    private final String CALLBACKURL = "SCHEME://HOST";

    private Twitter twitter;
    AccessToken a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        doAuth();
    }

    private void doAuth() {
        try {
            httpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey,
                    consumerSecret);
            httpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
                    "https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                    "https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                    "https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
            String authUrl = httpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(
                    httpOauthConsumer, CALLBACKURL);

            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse(authUrl)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACKURL)) {

            String verifier = uri
                    .getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            // this will populate token and token_secret in consumer
            try {
                httpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(httpOauthConsumer,
                        verifier);
            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //Important part where it actually sets the authorization so you can use it
            a = new AccessToken(httpOauthConsumer.getToken(),
                    httpOauthConsumer.getTokenSecret());
            twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

To make this work you need to make a couple adjustments to your Manifest.

- Give it permission to use internet:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

- Set the launch mode to `singleInstance`

```
    <activity
    android:name="com.example.eredivisietwitter.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
```

- Add this intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
    </action>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
    </category>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" >
    </category>

    <data
        android:host="HOST"
        android:scheme="SCHEME" >
    </data>
</intent-filter>
```

Make sure to have the same host and scheme in your Activity:

```
private final String CALLBACKURL = "SCHEME://HOST";
```

Now that you have successfully authorized your app you can use the `Twitter` object to request timelines etc.

Example:

```java
private void getTweets(String user) {

    try {
        List<Status> statuses;
        statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user);

        System.out.println("Showing @" + user + "'s user timeline.");
        for (Status status : statuses) {

            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName()
                    + " - " + status.getText());
        }

    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Voilá!

Comment: but the problem here is im just getting the tweets, i want the name profile pic and time as well....

Comment: Check out [the javadoc](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/index.html) to see is possible with twitter4j. There is a `showUser(long userId)` in `UserResources` which returns a `User`. A `User` then has `getProfileImageURL()` etc.

Comment: Can i get the full json by any method, like it was possible in api 1.0 ??

Comment: How can I extract the Image from the tweet