# How can we Follow a person on instagram from our app?

Tags: android, instagram

I am building an instagram app in which i will be showing the pics of target user which the user will write. Is it possible to follow the person from my app??

I used this code to like a pic in instagram.

```
try {
     URL url = new URL(API_URL + "/media/" + instapostid + "/likes?access_token=" + accessToken);
    Log.d(TAG, "Opening URL " + url.toString());
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();
```

where API_URL is

```
private static final String API_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look in the Instagram API Docs?

This seems like what you are looking for:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[user-id]/relationship?access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]
```

> Modify the relationship between the current user and the target user.

```
PARAMETERS:
ACCESS_TOKEN    A valid access token.
ACTION  One of: follow/unfollow/block/unblock/approve/deny.
```

So if you are logged in you should be able to send a POST to this url giving a target user-id an access-token and an action parameter of "follow"

[See this page for more](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/)

Comment: but i am unable to give the action = follow , how should i send it??

Comment: as a parameter of your post request.

Comment: im new to android programming, so can you plz tell me how to send the parameter??

Comment: [See examples here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/) look at the POST example and change the url and parameters to the ones you are using for instagram.

Comment: Thank you very much.... can you answer this ques as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559814/how-to-use-the-twitter4j-lib-to-get-the-tweets-of-screen-name

Comment: So should i write action=follow in params?? or just follow??

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
TextView txtFollow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFollow);
 txtFollow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/URL");
                    Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

                    likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

                    try {
                        startActivity(likeIng);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/URL")));
                    }

                }
 });
```

Comment: this is just an intent, the question is how to follow using Instagram API