# How to get tweet text from Adapters?

Tags: java, android, twitter, adapter, twitter-fabric

I have created an App that shows Twitter timeline by searching the user name.
I used fabricUI in this code. Everything works, but I also need to examine the text of all tweets.

I found that I can use `getView(int position)`, but only found how they use it for specific item with `onClickListener()`.

#### `TimelineActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected TweetTimelineListAdapter doInBackground(TweetTimelineListAdapter... param) {
    UserTimeline userTimeline = new Builder()
            .screenName(name)
            .build();
    TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(TimelineActivity.this, userTimeline);
    return adapter;
}
```

How can I use this way of getting twitter Timeline and also get all Tweets text to examine? At first I was thinking that I can "extract" the adapters information somehow, I think there's is another way.

Comment: You can get Tweet at any position using         adapter.getItem();

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
 get this error using adapter.getItem(0); @sahu

Comment: That means there are no elements present currently inside your adapter. First you should load some tweets. Check APIs for using UserTimeline. Once there are some tweets present inside your adapter then you can check them using that function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559814/how-to-use-the-twitter4j-lib-to-get-the-tweets-of-screen-name
Can someone tell me application created by this method will require every user to login? It only asked my information for "app authorization" @sahu

Comment: once the user has logged in you don't have to login again. It can use previous session. Is that your question ????

Comment: I understand what you mean and answered my question. Thank you. @sahu

Comment: If I answered your question then please accept the answer.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get Tweet at any position using adapter.getItem();

First you should load some tweets. Check APIs for using UserTimeline. Once there are some tweets present inside your adapter then you can check them using that function.

Once the app is authorised the user need not log in again. It uses the active session next time.

I hope it answered your question fully.

Thanks

Comment: No.  I am using SearchTimeline, and it still has 0 items.